# Wordpress move from host to local server

Tags: php, mysql, database, wordpress, database-migration

I am quite new to WordPress and PHP, so apologies for the questions that may sound a bit primitive. I have a site on WordPress but it's really slow and contains a lot of legacy code. What do I want is to create the new theme and make some optimization. For this reason, I want to move from Web to local storage and play around in a secure way. What do I have? A have SQL file and a copy of file system taken from the server via FTP. I put the site's copy to local OpenServer and via phpAdmin, with MySQL Workbench I have my site running on the local server. Of course, I have performed in phpMyAdmin this script:

```
SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES = 0;
UPDATE aw3ed6gb_options SET option_value = replace(option_value, 'https://fbs-tax.com','http://fbs-local') WHERE option_name = 'home' OR option_name = 'siteurl';
UPDATE aw3ed6gb_posts SET guid = replace(guid, 'https://fbs-tax.com','http://fbs-local'); 
UPDATE aw3ed6gb_posts SET post_content = replace(post_content, 'https://fbs-tax.com','http://fbs-local');
UPDATE aw3ed6gb_site SET domain='fbs-local' WHERE domain LIKE '%fbs-tax.com%';
UPDATE aw3ed6gb_sitemeta SET meta_value='http://fbs-local' WHERE `meta_value`LIKE '%fbs-tax.com%';
UPDATE aw3ed6gb_blogs SET domain = replace(domain, 'fbs-tax.com','fbs-local');
UPDATE aw3ed6gb_usermeta SET meta_value='fbs-local' WHERE meta_key='source_domain';
```

Also in my wp-config.php I have this:

```
define('WP_CACHE', true);
define( 'ADMIN_COOKIE_PATH', '/mygolad' );
define( 'WPCACHEHOME', __DIR__ . '/wp-content/plugins/wp-super-cache/' ); define('DB_NAME', 'db_local_0');
define('DB_USER', 'root');
define('DB_PASSWORD', '');
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8mb4');
define('DB_COLLATE', '');
define('SHORTPIXEL_API_KEY', 'eCRnNMw6yaf4ztoDM4F5');
```

The propblem is that when I try to access http://fbs-local/wp-admin I can not sign in with any user/pswrd.
So my questions are:

- how access to wp-admin;
- can I start a new WordPress project and then just add to it my DB;
- if second yes can I reformat SQL from 5.5 to 5.7;
- maybe the problem is in wrong DB copy;

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I often have to migrate wordpress websites and I always use [this plugin](https://de.wordpress.org/plugins/all-in-one-wp-migration/).

This saves you a lot of work.
It will copy all files (theme, plugins, media files etc.) and the database of your website.

You just need to install this plugin on your current website and export all data. After this you have to install the plugin on your local installation (a clean installation is recommended). Now you just have to import the file from the other website.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. As far as I have understood there is no need to save separately DB and File Structure? I will simply install it on my live website make a copy, store on my PC and then install one more time on localhost. Am I right?

Comment: You don't need to make a copy of your files and database. The plugin will do this for you. You can also watch this video how to use the plugin: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BpWxCeUWBOk

Comment: Thank you hope that will help me. I will test it on Monday.